# Is the margin of inline-block (4px) is static for all browsers?

Tags: css

Whenever I use inline-block I always get a **4px** margin. So can i safely use

```
div.myclass{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

for all browsers?

Here's the fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmsL7/)

Comment: You should remove the space characters that cause that gap.

Comment: Are you sure that is actually margin? It could also possibly be the padding of the parent wrapper.

Comment: even without HTML spaces, inline-block always gives a 4px margin

Comment: If you could provide something (e.g. html that you have, jsfiddle, etc) that would help on troubleshooting your problem

Comment: It's not a 4px margin ... it's the width of one space in that given font and font-size. This means that depending on font (and whether user has defined their own font/font-size settings) the size can change.

Comment: but i just have linebreaks between each elements @SLakes , no spaces

Comment: linebreaks are whitespace: http://jsfiddle.net/UcpG4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rmsL7/

Comment: You should really check using a debugger. It shows what are applied from which css settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on font-size of parent element. `inline-block` adds margin because of one extra whitespace character width. It's `4px` margin when font-size is default `14px`.

Anyways, you can check these two great articles here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ and here: http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/

Comment: Got it it's the whitespace :)